# Dropbox API Android listing contents of contents from directory

Tags: android, api, dropbox

I would like to list the content of the content of a directory from *Dropbox* using its *Android API*.
I tried using *dirEntry.contents()* in a *for* loop, like this:

```
Entry rootDirEnt = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null,
                true, null);

        if (!rootDirEnt.isDir || rootDirEnt.contents == null) {

            // It's not a directory, or there's nothing in it
            mErrorMsg = "No files available in Dropbox";
            return false;
        }

        for (Entry childDirEnt : rootDirEnt.contents) {

            // check if it still exists
            if (childDirEnt.isDir && !childDirEnt.isDeleted
                    && childDirEnt.contents != null) {

                // childDirEnt contents is already null, even though there are files inside this directory
                for (Entry fileEnt : childDirEnt.contents) {

                    // do smth with file
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        publishProgress();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I thought of usign mApi.metadata() again with the new path which works, but my question is: Can't I do it without calling medata() for every directory inside root dir ? (maybe using the contents call or smth.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `metadata` again on each directory you find. Generally, Dropbox discourages calling `metadata` recursively like that unless driven by user action. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/bestpractices.

You might instead use the `delta` API. The first time you call that, it will return a full list of all the content your app has access to in a user's Dropbox.

Comment: It looks to me like it's a little rough, but I'll try to manage it using your advice. Ty!